# A program that opens a text file, counts the number of words and reports the top N words ordered by the number of times they appear in the file?

Tags: python, file, word-count

Hi all im a beginner at programming, i was recently given the task of creating this program and i am finding it difficult. I have previously designed a program that calculates the number of words in a sentence that are typed in by the user, is it possible to modify this program to achieve what i want?

```
import string
def main():
  print "This program calculates the number of words in a sentence"
  print
  p = raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
  words = string.split(p)
  wordCount = len(words)
  print "The total word count is:", wordCount
main()
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried first. No one here is going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting words and [open()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for opening the file:

```
from collections import Counter
def main():
    #use open() for opening file.
    #Always use `with` statement as it'll automatically close the file for you.
    with open(r'C:\Data\test.txt') as f:
        #create a list of all words fetched from the file using a list comprehension
        words = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
        print "The total word count is:", len(words)
        #now use collections.Counter
        c = Counter(words)
        for word, count in c.most_common():
           print word, count
main()
```

`collections.Counter` example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter('aaaaabbbdddeeegggg')
```

[Counter.most_common](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) returns words in sorted order based on their count:

```
>>> for word, count in c.most_common(): 
...     print word,count
...     
a 5
g 4
b 3
e 3
d 3
```

Answer (score 1):

To open files, you can use the [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function

```
from collections import Counter
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    p = f.read() # p contains contents of entire file
    # logic to compute word counts follows here...

    words = p.split()

    wordCount = len(words)
    print "The total word count is:", wordCount

    # you want the top N words, so grab it as input
    N = int(raw_input("How many words do you want?"))

    c = Counter(words)
    for w, count in c.most_common(N):
       print w, count
```

Comment: fantastic! I was struggling with the input method thanks alot! However one problem, when the program asks me 'How many words do i want' i enter an integer for e.g. 30 and it gives me a massive error message

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('file_name.txt') as f:
    sentence = f.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
word_counts = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is getting the error message for input, you may like to try this one,

Code:

```
N = int(input("\nHow many words do you want: "))
```