# open: invalid mode or filename

Tags: python, file, word-count

This is the word count program. how could it be made more simple?

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('C:\Data\test.txt') as f:
passage = f.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)

cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words]

word_counts = Counter(cap_words)
```

keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/wordcount", line 4, in <module>
with open('C:\Data\test.txt') as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Data\test.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a raw string or escape each `\` with a `\`. That is required because without it `'\t'` will be converted to a tab space:

```
r'C:\Data\test.txt'
```

Example:

```
>>> print 'C:\Data\test.txt'
C:\Data est.txt                 #\t is converted to tab
>>> print r'C:\Data\test.txt'   
C:\Data\test.txt                #here it is fine

>>> print 'C:\\Data\\test.txt'  #same as raw string, but manual escaping
C:\Data\test.txt
```

Comment: Or he can just use `'C:\\Data\\test.txt'`.

Comment: i tried using the double back slash and no error messages appeared. however when i actually run the program nothing appears it just says 'restart' why is this?

Comment: @user2554477 You aren't printing anything in your program, what do you expect it to print?

Comment: @user2554477 look at my previous solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17493530/846892

Comment: I see, apologies i am a beginner